# How to convert an Objective-c block into Ruby?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am building a iOS app using Rubymotion.
I need to "convert" a piece of Objective-c code into Ruby.
Is this correct?

**Originally in Objective-c**

```
[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
          [filter removeTarget:movieWriter];
          [movieWriter finishRecording];
      }];
```

**Same thing in Ruby?:**

```
  movieWriter(setCompletionBlock:-> { filter.removeTarget(movieWriter) }, { movieWriter.finishRecording })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The syntax for message sends in Ruby is not `object(message:arguments)` and the syntax for having multiple statements in a block is not `{statement1} {statement2}`. Instead, you'd want something like this:

```
movieWriter.completionBlock = lambda do
  filter.removeTarget(movieWriter)
  movieWriter.finishRecording
end
```

(RubyMotion translates setters like `completionBlock=` into the appropriate `setCompletionBlock:` method. If you wanted to use the explicit setter method, it would look like `movieWriter.setCompletionBlock(lambda do …)`.)

Comment: You could also do: `movieWriter.completionBlock = lambda{
  filter.removeTarget movieWriter
  movieWriter.finishRecording
}`

Comment: @Napalm: I don't believe that is valid code — in particular, `movieWriter movieWriter.finishRecording` can't possibly be right, as `movieWriter` is clearly not a method.

Comment: It's `filter.removeTarget movieWriter` on the same line.